# DocuSign Apex API: Add sign here and date tabs

Tags: docusignapi, apex

I have implemented Docusign's embedded signing using the apex toolkit for docusign. I have stored my document to be signed in Documents object. I want to add the sign here tab to the document and then send it to docusign. ANy ideas on how can I achieve this?

Below is the code i've used to generate the envelope. I need to add the sign here tab to the envelope:

```
    Id mySourceId = '0012v00002WathI'; 
    Id myDocumentId = '0692v00000AF1yP'; 
    dfsle.Envelope myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.getEmptyEnvelope(
        new dfsle.Entity(mySourceId)) // The initiating Salesforce entity.
        .withDocuments(dfsle.DocumentService.getDocuments(
                ContentVersion.getSObjectType(), 
                new Set<Id> { 
                    myDocumentId 
                }))
        .withRecipients(new List<dfsle.Recipient> {
            dfsle.Recipient.newEmbeddedSigner(), 

        });

    myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelope(
        myEnvelope, // The envelope to send
        true); // Send now?
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but from what I remember when working with the apex toolkit it does not allow you to add tags to documents through Apex. I'm pretty sure what you have there should work and when you initiate the embedded signing process you will get to choose where the sign tags go. You could set up a template for this document to decide where the tags go beforehand (which is useful if you send the same document often) for how to add documents with templates to envelopes see [this page](https://developers.docusign.com/salesforce/code-examples/salesforce-sending-signing-template) at step 3. The toolkit documentation isn't very clear so you may want to watch a demo to see how the whole process works like [this one](https://youtu.be/9cHqoCkyg5k). Hope this helps.